# Toggle between mouse clicks at two positions

Tags: autohotkey

I want to press a hotkey, "x", to trigger mouse clicks that alternate between two positions

If I press "x", the mouse should click at position A
If I press "x" again, the mouse should click at position B
If I press "x" again, the mouse should click at position A
and so on

Here is my pseudocode

global variable "i"
i = 0

```
x::
   if (i % 2 = 0) {
         Click position A
      } else {
         Click position B
      }
      i = i + 1
   }
return
```

I don't know how to do this in Autohotkey, please help

Answer (score 0):

here is an example

```
x::
if (toggle := !toggle)
    MsgBox A
else
    MsgBox B
return
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my question: I want the toggle to change every time I press "x". Pressing X the first time clicks position A, pressing X the second time clicks position B, and so on

Comment: Updated my answer above